# Reference request for a Riemannian Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am looking for any reference which states, and proves, a Fokker-Planck equation for Riemannian manifolds.

In particular, if $\mathrm{d}X_t=\mu(X_t)~\mathrm{d}t + \sigma(X_t)~\mathrm{d}B_t$ is a stochastic differential equation on a manifold, I want to relate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to the time evolution of the density of $X_t$, just like the Euclidean Fokker-Planck equation. It would be great if there is a global description of the time evolution, but a local coordinate expression would be okay too.

Comment: I don't know the answer or if it'll make a difference, but is the restriction to autonomous SDE intentional?

Comment: It just so happens that my SDEs are time homogenous, so I would be happy with a variant of the Fokker-Planck equation for time-homogenous SDEs.

Comment: cross-posted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/439710/11260